# Oscillation of a rolling sphere in a bowl

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, oscillators

This is a homework task. I already came to a result but I am very unsure.

The task: In a bowl with the shape of a semi-circle ($R$ = 0.5m) a sphere (there is no specification for the size of the sphere) is rolling without friction. Calculate the period of the oscillation. Use approximation for a small amplitude.
Original problem description (German):

```
In einer Wanne mit halbkreisförmigem Querschnitt (Radius $R = 0.5m$) rollt ein kleines
Kügelchen reibungsfrei hin- und her.
```

[image: Sphere oscillating by rolling in bowl]

```
Berechnen Sie die Schwingungsfrequenz dieser Bewegung für kleine Auslenkungen.
```

My solution: Using Newton 2 I make up the equality of torque: The first term is the inertia of the sphere according to the linear movement, the second term is the torque caused by gravity and the third term is the inertia according to the rotation of the sphere, $r$ is the radius of the sphere.

$$mR^2*\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2} + mgR*\phi + \frac{d\phi}{dt^2}*\frac{R}{r}*\frac25mr^2 = 0$$

$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}*(mR^2+\frac25mr^2\frac{R}{r}) = - mgR*\phi$$

$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2} = - \frac{mgR}{(mR^2+\frac25mr^2\frac{R}{r})}*\phi$$

$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2} = - \frac{g}{R+\frac25r}*\phi$$

This is a standard differential equation for oscillation and solving it yields:

$$T = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{R+\frac25r}{g}}$$

for the period $T$. It makes sense that $T$ is higher the bigger the radius of the sphere is but I can't calculate it with $r$ being unspecified.
Is there an error in my solution or is the task unsolvable?

Comment: Usually, if the radius of the sphere is not mentioned, ignore it! If you put $r=0$, you get [a standard solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Small-angle_approximation) for the small-angle oscillatory motion.

Comment: If I could assume $r$ -> $0$ it had surely been mentioned in the task description. If my solution is correct I will submit the formula for $T$ as it is without calculating it.

Comment: But by not stating *what* $r$ is in the problem statement, it is *implicitly* defined as ignorable (i.e., $r\simeq0$).

Comment: I'd have to agree with Kyle on this one. You're making it harder than it has to be by adding the radius of the bead. Since you said this was homework, however, I would submit both answers to the professor and see what he was looking for.

Comment: You could also solve this the Lagrangian way with a constraint ($x^{2}+y^{2} - R^{2} = 0$). It might be quicker and less messy.

Comment: @astromax: I'm going to disagree on the Lagrangian method. With Newton 2, it's simply $mR^2d^2\theta/dt^2=mgR\cos\theta\simeq mgR\theta$ and you're done. With the Lagrangian, you have $L=\frac12mR^2\dot{\theta}^2+mgR\cos\theta$ then the Euler equations before you get to what Newton did in a single line.

Comment: I added the original description. May those who understand it judge by themselves

Comment: @Machtl: `kleines Kügelchen` = small bead $\to$ ignorable radius. That is nearly standard language for this problem.

Comment: Okay I added it to may submission, thank you very much

Comment: It does take a couple of lines of extra work, but you can neatly handle the constraint equation. Plus, I said you could also solve this by constructing the Lagrangian, not you "should" solve it this way. There is nothing to "disagree" on, unless you are making the claim that it cannot be done this way.

Comment: There is a far easier way to to it in a single line of math: note that the potential is locally an isotropic 2D quadratic form. A 2D analysis with angle $\phi$ is thus unnecessary. I'll post it as a solution in a minute.

Comment: If there truly is no friction, wouldn't the bead slide instead of roll?

Comment: @JulianRosen: Yes, the ball will slide instead of roll.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos, Machtl: the small radius is not given, but rolling is mentioned, hence rotation of the marble has to be accounted for. The resulting motion of marble, however small, is different from that of a sliding mass point. See the answer by Julian Rosen.

Comment: Interesting that the answer comes out different for the rolling vs. sliding case, I would have naively guessed they might be the same, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different approach, giving a different answer.

I will choose a coordinate system so that the angle $\phi=0$ is downward, and normalize the center of the bowl to have 0 gravitational potential. I will also assume $r\ll R$.

The gravitational potential energy of the bead is
$$
-mgR\cos\phi.
$$

The kinetic energy of a rolling (solid) ball of constant density is $\frac{7}{10}mv^2$ (where $v$ is the velocity of the center of the ball), so the kinetic energy of the marble is
$$
\frac{7}{10}m\left(R\frac{d\phi}{dt}\right)^2.
$$
Setting the derivative of the total energy equal to 0 gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
mgR\sin\phi\frac{d\phi}{dt}+\frac{7}{5}mR^2\frac{d\phi}{dt}\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}&=&0,\\
\sin\phi+\frac{7}{5}\frac{R}{g}\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}&=&0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Using the approximation $\sin\phi\sim\phi$ for $|\phi|$ small:
$$
\phi+\frac{7R}{5g}\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2}=0,
$$
so the period of oscillation is
$$
T=\frac{2\pi\sqrt{7R}}{\sqrt{5g}}.
$$

I believe the reason we have arrived at two different answers is the following: the problem statement seems to imply that (i) the marble is rolling, and (ii) there is no friction. Statments (i) and (ii) are inconsistent, so we must abandon one of them. In my opinion, the question is more interesting if we we keep (i) and drop (ii). If we assume the marble is rolling instead of sliding, then there necessarily must be friction between the bowl and the marble. The friction causes a torque, which is not included in the OP's computation. If one calculates the frictional force (using the fact that the marble rolls) and includes it in the OP's computation, I believe this gives the same answer I gave.

Comment: Very nice solution. One could use this method also for larger marble if its radius $r$ is given. The potential energy of the marble is given by the position of its center of gravity, $-mg(R-r)\cos \phi$. The steps are then the same as Julian has shown.

Comment: Also, in the large marble case, the kinetic energy is $\frac{7}{10}m\left((R-r)\frac{d\phi}{dt}\right)^2$

Comment: True! (I was quick enough to not realize that:-)

Comment: Your solution is the same as mine with $r = R$. Interesting in previous tries I came up with your result but discarded because I thought it was incorrect. I need to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

A 1-D analysis will suffice. We have $U(x)\approx\frac{mg}{2R}x^2$, and thus we solve the relevant DEQ $mx''(t)=-U'(x(t))$ to obtain $$\tau=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{R}{g}}=1.418\mbox{ sec}.$$

`Side note`: The reasoning for the reduction to the 1-D case follows since the 2D potential is $$U(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{2}mg \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{R} & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{R}
\end{array}\right):\mathbf{r}\otimes\mathbf{r}+O(\mathbf{r}^3)$$ which means the system is a 2D isotropic oscillator for small oscillation.

`EDIT`: This assumes the small ball is sliding around the bowl (due to the frictionless surface not being able to impart a torque on it as it moves), and not rolling around. See Julian Rosen's answer for the rolling interpretation.